# android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity is added in Build Intermediate Androidmainfest.xml in Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-recyclerview

I recently used the `recyleview` support library and I am seeing that it is creating a intermediate file of `AndroidMainfest.xml` with `android.support.v7.widget.TestActivity` in that. I don't want this activity to be created as it is giving error while running the app. I am using `gradle 1.3.0` version.

Do any one know how can I remove it?

[image]

Comment: post your Androidmanifest file and build.gradle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use remove tool in androidMainfest for that activity and it will remove the activity from Mainfest.